# CAC authentication on tomcat server

Tags: tomcat8, keystore, smartcard, cac

How does a DOD CAC card validation works if our code is deployed on a tomcat server? 
Do we need to store the certificate authority file of DOD on a keystore (as trust store) and then give the path of this keystore in server.xml file of tomcat?

Is there any other approach with which we can authenticate a DOD smart card?

If those authorities file have to be loaded on server's trust store then which all files are required to be loaded and from where to download those certificate authority files?